# Why does the bubble sort program show the garbage value when using "break" in for loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, break

This code will take the elements of the array from the user and then sort it. The user input limit is 20. I have an issue with a specific line which is `if (a[i]==0)break;` if I use break here the result shows garbage values. Otherwise, it works fine but I want the user to be able to run the program with 20 or fewer numbers. I meant they can simply enter 0 whenever they feel they are done, and so the loop breaks. I am giving the code below. Please try to give simple solutions and don't be toxic and snooty. Thank you.

```
//Sorting with user input array elements
void print(float a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
}

void sort(float a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                swap(a[j], a[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    float a[20];
    int size;
    court << "Enter Floats and terminate with 0 (Highest limit is 20)" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        cout << "a[" << i << "] : ";
        cin >> a[i];
        if (a[i] == 0)
            break;
    }
    size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);

    cout << "\nGiven Values   :: ";
    print(a, size);
    cout << endl;
    sort(a, size);
    cout << "Sorted Result    :: ";
    print(a, size);
}
```

Comment: The array has size 20. The user sets values until 0 is entered. That means that the other elements are uninitialized. These are the garbage values. You can fix it by saving the number of entered elements.

Comment: How can I save the number of entered elements? I mean I already used "size" to determine the size after user input.

Comment: The loop continues until `i == 20`.  Which means (unless the user enters a value of zero before that) that a value will be read past the end of the array.   The result is undefined behaviour.

Comment: The size of an array is fixed. It doesn't change. `sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);` will always return `20`.

Comment: _"Please, ...don't be toxic and snooty"_ — Please, don't write this, it does not belong to the question and it's kind-of impolite to the vast majority of readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array has size 20. The user sets values until 0 is entered. That means that the other elements are uninitialized. These are the garbage values. You can fix it by saving the number of entered elements.

```
//Sorting with user input array elements
void print(float a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
}

void sort(float a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                swap(a[j], a[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    float a[20];
    int size{0};
    court << "Enter Floats and terminate with 0 (Highest limit is 20)" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cout << "a[" << i << "] : ";
        cin >> a[i];
        if (a[i] == 0)
            break;
        ++size;
    }

    cout << "\nGiven Values   :: ";
    print(a, size);
    cout << endl;
    sort(a, size);
    cout << "Sorted Result    :: ";
    print(a, size);
}
```

There is also a problem in the for loop. The array has size 20 but the for loop starts with 0 and iterates until 20 inclusive. That are 21 iterations. I fixed it in my answer.